# How to stop loop when user enters "quit", "end", etc?

Tags: python

This is my code

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3.1$                                                                            
 #Break Statement$                                                                                
 while True:$                                                                                     
    s=(input('enter an string: '))$                                                              
    if s=='Quit,quit,End,end':$                                                                  
        break$                                                                                   
    print('Your string length is',len(s))$                                                       
 print("done")$
```

Here my program fails to check the condition....even if it checks it even calculates for the length for 'quit,Quit,End,end' -- any ideas why?

Comment: Lose the `$` symbols. That code is broken

Comment: do you really want to quit if the user types "Quit,quit,End,end" ? don't you think "give me a solution" is a nice way to ask for help? I would say, be polite or go somewhere else but that wouldn't be nice of me either.

Comment: I assume that this is Python 3?

Comment: s == 'Quit,quit,End,end' will only be true when s is 'Quit,quit,End,end' ... usually a user only wants to enter one, not the entire string. To show this to yourself, type in the entire string ('Quit,quit,End,end', with correct capitalization and without the quotes) and see the program function "as expected".

Answer (score 7):

You should not have `$` at the end of every line.

Also, instead of this:

```
if s=='Quit,quit,End,end':
```

you want to use `in` and a list:

```
if s in ['Quit','quit','End','end']:
```

You can also handle other inputs such as `QUIT` and `QUit` by using [`str.lower`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower):

```
if s.lower() in ['quit', 'end']:
```

Comment: Just avoids quitting accidentally. What? Oh, I know what you're thinking--just pop up a dialog box asking if they're sure. That's for suckers.